# Importing an array from text file and convert it to truth table

Tags: boolean-computation

I am new to *Mathematica*, and would like some help in the following operation. I have a truth table stored in a text file. I want to read this in *Mathematica*, and find its Boolean Rule. Suppose I have two Boolean variables. I am reading the text file in *Mathematica* like this:

```
arr=Import["bool.txt","Table"]
```

Suppose this array is arr=

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

The third column represents the output, and the first two columns are the states of the inputs. For finding the Boolean rule, I need to convert this array as an association of

```
table={{0,0}->0,{0,1}->1,{1,0}->1,{1,1}->1}
```

So that I can infer the Boolean rule using the following function:

```
BooleanFunction[table,{x,y}]
```

My problem is, I don't know how to create the variable `table`, from the array `arr`. I looked up a bit and think the `Association` function would be used, but not sure how. I need to do it for multiple text files, and am looking to develop a short program for this functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Map`:

```
table = (Most[#] -> Last[#])& /@ arr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is as good as the above method.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do:

```
{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

> ```
> {{0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 1}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simply a line of code is sufficient I see {#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ arr.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html?q=Thread):

```
table = Thread[arr[[All, ;; 2]] -> arr[[All, -1]]]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 1}
> ```

Comment: Very useful to know, thanks :)